# Getting text only when nokogiri certain HTML structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I've been struggling with nokogiri lib in order to fetch (scrape) content from web, I failed to understand how to get only text without nested tags. 
Here is what I parse

```
<div class="line1">text I need
<br><div class="podp_k">group:</div><a class="GR" title="go to this group" href="#" rel="?sectID=2">group 1</a>
<br>
<div class="podp_k">brand:</div><a class="BR" title="go to brand" href="#" rel="?sectID=0&amp;brand=16">China&nbsp;&nbsp;CHINA</a>
</div>
```

Here is the way I scrape it

```
tagcloud_elements = nokogiri_object.css("div#products_tbody > table > tbody > tr > td > div.line1 > text()")
f.puts tagcloud_element.text.gsub(/^\s+/,'')
```

the gsub at the end does almost exactly I need, but I lefts number of whitespaces after. Can anybody suggest the best way to get only "text I need" from the above example please?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". What is your expected output? Any time you have a long list of selectors you've made your code more fragile. If the HTML changes the selector will very likely break. Instead, if you can't find the exact tag(s) you want directly, find placeholders in the HTML, navigate to them, then jump to the next until you get what you want. Your resulting code will be much more resilient.

Comment: Be very careful using long selectors that define every intervening tag to your destination, such as `"div#products_tbody > table > tbody > tr > td > div.line1 > text()"`. If the HTML changes your code will break. Instead, find based on a simple selector like `div#products_tbody div.line1`. That way the table can disappear and if the content remains inside `div.line1` you'll find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would delete the other nodes that are in this section if you're not using the document any further.

```
nokogiri_object.css("div.line1 *").each(&:remove)
nokogiri_object.at_css("div.line1").text.strip # => "text I need"
```

Comment: it actually deletes "text I need" as well :(